# Magento 2: I need to remove .html from all product page url

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite, product-urls

I am trying to remove ".html" from the URL. Attached are my catalog SEO setting in the Magento 2. As you can see I have remove the ".html" from Product URL Suffix.

[image]

I have already tried below solution but no luck

**Soln1:** php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**Soln2:**  1). Delete all records from table url_rewrite. You can run the following SQL command: DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'product';

2).Login to your Magento 2 backend >> Re-save all your Categories and then run this command :- php bin/magento cache:flush

Please help me with this issue.

I am using Magento 2.3.

Thanks In advance..!!

Comment: Have You tried cache:clean? (You mentioned only about indexer and cache:flush)

Comment: second option is try to .htaccess file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245032/remove-html-from-urls-with-a-redirect

Comment: @lama377 : Yes I tried cache:clean also.

Comment: @MohitPatel: I'll check this

Comment: Okay Sure, any need help Please comment @BalwantSingh

Comment: @MohitPatel : not worked for me. some of the page URLs going to 404 after that solution.

Comment: Yes your are apply this solution but Please confirm your multiple store website ??? If yes , So Please select your store and after apply this solution https://blog.equaltrue.com/how-to-remove-html-from-url-in-magento-2-for-search-engine-optimization/